# Möbius inversion exercise

Tags: sequences-and-series, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

I have been given the following exercise:

Get a function $G(x)$ so that, being $x$ a positive integer,

$$x+\sqrt{x}= \sum^x_{n=1} \mu(n) G(\frac{x}{n})$$

The result does not have to be exact, but it must approach to the equation as $x \to \infty$. In other words, there can be an error term $E(x)$ if it does not diverge.

My try:

We know that $$F(x)=\sum \mu(n) G(\frac{x}{n})$$ iff $$G(x)=\sum F(\frac{x}{n})$$

Then, $$G(x)=\sum \frac{x}{n}+ \sqrt{\frac{x}{n}}=x\log x + \gamma x +1 +2x +\zeta (1/2) \sqrt{x} +E(x)$$

Where $E(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

The problem is that, when I try to compute:

$$\sum^x_{n=1} \mu(n) \left ( \frac{x}{n}\log \frac{x}{n} + \gamma \frac{x}{n} +1 +2\frac{x}{n} +\zeta (1/2) \sqrt{\frac{x}{n}} \right ) $$

I always get a much larger result than what I need (i.e. $x+\sqrt{x}$).

Any help finding the flaw?

Thanks!

Edit: changed $+\frac{1}{2}$ to $+1$,

Comment: Your $\sum$ should be $\sum_{n\mid x}$, not $\sum_{n\le x}$.

Comment: @Hagen I use the first formula of https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_inversion_formula (Generalizations section)

Comment: How do you evaluate/approximate $\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{\mu(n)}{n}$? Are you aware that $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ for any $s>1$?

Comment: @Jack Sorry but, where? I do not get $\sum \frac{\mu(n)}{n}$ anywhere but at the end, and I compute the whole sum as-is (using mathematica)

Comment: When you compute the last sum, you have to deal with $\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}$ at $s=1$ and $s=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{x}\frac{\mu(n)\log(n)}{n}$. How did you deal with such terms when "trying to compute" your last sum? Why did you get a "much larger" result than expected?

Comment: It is simply impossible for us to *find the flaw* if you do not share such details.

Comment: @Jack Thank you for your interest and sorry if I am not expressing myself well. When I said that I computed the last sum, I did not divided it into smaller sums. I just introduced that "code" into Mathematica and let, for instance, $x=20000$. Playing with larger values of $x$ is enough to suspect that the asymptotic of the sum is not $x+\sqrt{x}$